# React Native - Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(DeckList)"

Tags: redux, react-navigation

Hi guyz I have a problem, I start using React Native with Redux and I am getting this error:

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in
>   the context of "Connect(DeckList)". Either wrap the root component in
>   a , or pass a custom React context provider to 
>   and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(DeckList) in
>   connect options.

I made react native app using expo and I am using react navigation v3.

I want to access store in my DeckList.js.

Here is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import { white, purple } from "./utils/colors";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons, FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import DeckList from "./components/DeckList";
import AddDeck from "./components/AddDeck";
import DeckView from "./components/DeckView";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducers";


export default function App() {
  const store = createStore(reducer);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {" "}
        <AppContainer />{" "}
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});

const Home = createBottomTabNavigator({
  DeckList: {
    screen: DeckList,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Home",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cards" size={24} color={tintColor} />
      )
    }
  },
  AddDeck: {
    screen: AddDeck,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "ADD",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <FontAwesome name="plus-square" size={24} color={tintColor} />
      )
    }
  }
});

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  DeckList: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Home",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cards" size={24} color={tintColor} />
      )
    }
  },
  DeckView: {
    screen: DeckView,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Deck Indo",
      headerTinitColor: white,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: purple
      }
    }
  }
});
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Here is DeckList.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import { getData } from "../utils/api";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class DeckList extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    const decks = getData();

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Object.keys(decks).map((deck, i) => {
          const { title, questions } = decks[deck];
          return (
            <View key={i}>
              <Text>{title}</Text>
              <Text>{questions.length}</Text>
              <Button
                title="View Deck"
                onPress={() =>
                  this.props.navigation.navigate("DeckView", { entryId: deck })
                }
              />
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    decks: state
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DeckList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create the store outside the render function:

```
const store = createStore(reducer);

export default function App() {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {" "}
        <AppContainer />{" "}
      </View>
    </Provider>
   );
}
```